# How to cancel sub Timer inside nested Timer?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am having a problem with cancelling one nested Timer. These are the code example I have:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() async{
 final timer =
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      print('Timer 1');
      Timer(const Duration(seconds:1),(){
        print('Timer 2');
      });
    });
  
  Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1500),(){
    timer.cancel();    
        print('timer cancelled');
      });
}
```

The result:

```
Timer 1
timer cancelled
Timer 2
```

What I am expected:

```
Timer 1
timer cancelled
```

A little about my usecase, I want to create a quite complex animation and I use the nested Timer to set the specific timing of the animation.

The problem occur when the user move forward and instantinously move backward, the animation that still inside the Timer will still run 'forward' (because it's still deep inside the nested timer) even though the 'reverse' animation should be the only one that run.

That is why I am only expecting Timer 1 to be printed instead of both Timer 1 and 2 even though the Timer has been cancelled

Any feedback or input would be appreciated.

What I am expected:

```
Timer 1
timer cancelled
```

Comment: why need nested time you can use future.delay to run animation after delay if you need to play animation after some time

Comment: "I want to create a quite complex animation and ..." so use `AnimationController`, not `Timers`s

Comment: @AliHassan I have tried both Timer and future.delayed and haven't found success. adding more context, when the user step forward, and the 'forward' animation runs the animations I'm delaying will be in await and runs one by one depending on the duration im waiting, the problem occurs when the user step forward and instantaneously step backward. what I want to achieve is that finish all the forward animation and then go to the reverse animation, but what happened all the future.delayed are mix together. so 1s Duration on the forward motion will mix with 1s duration of reverse animation.

Comment: @pskink what inside the Timer is animation controller forward or reverse. to make it simple I use print to simulate the animation. The Timer is the delay of animation.

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve? what is that complex animation?

Comment: @pskink I have 4 forward and reverse animations and will run by specific delay, each delay is different.I build the delay with timer and future.delay both havent found success. The problem is when the user step forward and forward animation is running. If the user not waiting the forward animation to finish and decide to go back. The reverse animation will mix with the forward delay duration. For example. I have 4 animations with 1s delay each. If the user go back on the 2 second. The 3rd and 4th forward animation will mix with reverse animation, because both 3rd forward and 1st reverse is 1s.

Comment: So the delay stack would be: 3rd (forward), 1st (backward), 4th (forward), 2nd (backward), 3rd and 4th backward. What I want is to finish all the forward delayed first, then the reverse animation delay run. Or cancel the forward delay altogether.

Comment: what about [staggered animations](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this will print your expected result.  Just keep a reference to the second `Timer`.  You can reuse the existing `timer` variable since after the first `Timer` fires to create the second `Timer`, you no longer need a reference to the first one.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main(List<String> args) {
  Timer? timer = null;
    timer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      print('Timer 1');
      timer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1),(){
        print('Timer 2');
      });
    });
  
  Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1500),(){
    timer?.cancel();    
        print('timer cancelled');
      });
}
```